# How do I pass instances of the main class to multiple listeners?

Tags: java, listener, bukkit

So, I've been working on a plugin. It was going great, until I stumbled on an issue. I'm using separate Listener (`implements Listener`) classes to manage my events, but for some of them, I need to access `JavaPlugin` methods, like for getting the configuration file.

Using the constructor **below** in my listener class works, but if I try to use the same thing in another class, Eclipse gives it a lovely red underline, saying `blank final field plugin may have not been initialized`

```
private final MainClass plugin;
public ListenerClass(MainClass instance){
    this.plugin = instance;
}
```

As said before, the above code works, but only for one listener.
The constructor **below** throws an NPE when using a method that returns an object. I don't know if this is because the plugin instance is *actually* returning as `null` or if there is no handle for *if* it is `null`.

```
// The only difference between this constructor and the last is that the final
// modifier was removed.
private MainClass plugin;
public ListenerClass(MainClass instance){
    this.plugin = instance;
}

FileConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig(); // throws NPE
// Let's pretend that the line above isn't there, and I just use the getConfig() method instead.

@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event){
    if(plugin.getConfig().getString("Strings.cat-toy").toLowerCase().equals("string")){ // throws NPE
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do something a lot different than most people do. Say your class that `extends JavaPlugin` is `Main.java`, you would add the following code NOT inside of any methods:

```
public static Main plugin;
```

then add this in your `onEnable()`:

```
plugin = this
```

So, your `Main` class could look something like this.

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
  public static Main plugin; //create the variable

  @Override
  public void onEnable(){
    plugin = this; //assign plugin to this class
    //other onEnable things
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisable(){
    //onDisable things
    plugin = null; //best to put this AFTER running any methods here
  }
}
```

Then, in any class that you want to use the `JavaPlugin` methods in, just use `Main.plugin`

So, if you wanted to get the config for your plugin in another class, you could do:

```
YamlConfiguration config = Main.plugin.getConfig();
```

Just make sure that you do this AFTER you assign `plugin` to your Main file. Let's say `Handler.setup()` uses `YamlConfiguration config = Main.plugin.getConfig();` in it, and you want to run that method when your plugin is enabled. You could do this:

```
public void onEnable(){
  plugin = this;
  Handler.setup();
}
```

But **NOT** this:

```
public void onEnable(){
  Handler.setup();
  plugin = this;
}
```

Comment: Yup. I was messing around with it and I realized that `Plugin` objects inherit the same methods as `JavaPlugin` objects. I did something very similar to that and it works. Thanks a lot! I've been snagged up on this for a month or two now.

Be sure to set `plugin` to `null` in your `onDisable()` method to prevent memory leaks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to re-invent the [Singleton Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm).

```
public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin {
    private static MainClass instance;
    public MainClass() {
        instance = this;
    }
    public static MainClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Listener listener = new ListenerClass();
    }
}
```

You may now access the instance directly, without making a member variable inside `ListenerClass`.

```
public class ListenerClass implements Listener {
    public ListenerClass() {
        Plugin main = MainClass.getInstance();
        main.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, main);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't put it in the constructor, it needs to be in onEnable, that's what onEnable is for. The plugin loader has 3 different constructors in the JavaPlugin class so you can't just put it in that one.

Comment: @gogobebe2 Making that one not-public won't let the plugin load, thus it should always be called.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: @gogobebe2 If you declare a private, empty constructor, your plugin won't load. That's why I think it will always be called.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. But using the constructor in spigot for the main class is considered bad. Maybe there's a reason why it's frowned upon. Have you tested using it in the constructor before? Also, there's a reason why there's an onEnable() method, I think it's better to use it in case there are bugs caused from things like the server reloading.