# "Abnormal Plugin Type" Error

Tags: bukkit

Using CraftBukkit 1.7.9 as a External Jar File (Build Path)

**Note:** My server is running CraftBukkit 1.7.9

Hello,

Whenever I use this plugin (CustomJoinSigns), a whole bunch of error logs will appear:

```
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO ... 10 more
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.(PluginClassLoader.java:52) ~[Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: me.pvpcraftnetwork.customjoinsigns.Main
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:436) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:126) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedPlayerList.(SourceFile:14) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PlayerList.(PlayerList.java:68) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.(CraftServer.java:317) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:355) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:328) ~[Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:127) ~[Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.(PluginClassLoader.java:56) ~[Bukkit_Dev.1.7.9.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-1-g5786276-b3085jnks]
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] INFO org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Abnormal plugin type
24.05 09:19:09 [Server] ERROR Could not load 'plugins/CustomJoinSigns.jar' in folder 'plugins'
```

Here is the plugin:

```
package me.pvpcraftnetwork.customjoinsigns;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.block.SignChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
        public static Bukkit plugin;

        public final HashMap<Location, String> signs =  new HashMap<Location, String>();

        public Main(Bukkit instance) {

        plugin = instance;
        }

        public void onEnable() {
            getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been enabled!");
        }

        public void onDisable() {
            getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been disabled!");
        } 
        @EventHandler
        public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent event){
            if(event.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Minigame")) {
                signs.put(event.getBlock().getLocation(), event.getPlayer().getName());
                event.getPlayer().sendMessage("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} Custom Join Sign created! Now type in: /cjs [Custom Join Sign Arena Number] setarenaname");
            }
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event){
            Player player = event.getPlayer();  
            if(signs.containsKey(event.getBlock().getLocation()) && !signs.containsValue(event.getPlayer().getName()) || !player.isOp()) {
                event.setCancelled(true);   
            } else {
                signs.remove(event.getBlock().getLocation());
            }
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
            Player player = event.getPlayer();
            if(signs.containsKey(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation())) {
                player.teleport(player.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why it isn't working. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you find the answer that you think is the best, click the check mark underneath the voting to accept it so others can find the answer. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the constructor in your `Main` class. It is invalid:

```
public Main(Bukkit instance){
    plugin = instance;
}
```

If you want to access the main class from anywhere else, you could add this in your Main class **NOT** inside of any methods:

```
public static Main plugin;
```

then add this in your `onEnable()`:

```
plugin = this;
```

So, your `onEnable()` method could look like this:

```
public void onEnable(){
  plugin = this;//assign the plugin to this class
  getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been disabled!");
}
```

I explain that a lot more in-depth [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529640/bukkit-how-do-i-pass-instances-of-the-main-javaplugin-class-to-multiple-list/23529865#23529865).

So, your main class should look like this:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public static Bukkit plugin;

    public final HashMap<Location, String> signs =  new HashMap<Location, String>();

    public static Main plugin;//access this class by using Main.plugin

    public void onEnable(){
        plugin = this;//assign the plugin variable to this class. Make SURE that you do this first!
        getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been enabled!");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        plugin = null;//set the plugin to null to prevent memory leaks
        getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been disabled!");
    } 
    @EventHandler
    public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent event){
        if(event.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Minigame")) {
            signs.put(event.getBlock().getLocation(), event.getPlayer().getName());
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} Custom Join Sign created! Now type in: /cjs [Custom Join Sign Arena Number] setarenaname");
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event){
        Player player = event.getPlayer();  
        if(signs.containsKey(event.getBlock().getLocation()) && !signs.containsValue(event.getPlayer().getName()) || !player.isOp()) {
            event.setCancelled(true);   
        } else {
            signs.remove(event.getBlock().getLocation());
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if(signs.containsKey(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation())) {
            player.teleport(player.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a plugin with a non-default constructor.

```
public Main(Bukkit instance) {
    plugin = instance;
}
```

Is invalid. To start, `Bukkit` is the main server's interface, not your plugin instance. If you want a public static instance of your plugin, then you would use:

```
public static Main instance;

public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
}
```

However I would say this is a bad design practice as well. Any managers or worker classes should just have a class instance passed to it:

```
public class SomeManager {

    private final Main plugin;

    public SomeManager(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

}
```

In your main class then:

```
private SomeManager something;

public void onEnable() {
    this.something = new SomeManager(this);
}
```